# Xamarin.Android: open specific event in calendar from another app

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, microsoft-graph-api

I'm currently working on an app in Xamarin.Android with one of the features being that, upon clicking a button, the user is taken to a specific calendar event in the Microsoft Outlook app. Thus far I've been using the Microsoft Graph API to get the event items and I've succeeded in opening the Outlook app to the calendar or opening Outlook with an error message saying "Event could not be opened" but I haven't gotten both behaviors to happen, nor the specific event item to open. The way I open the Outlook app is by calling the device's default browser with an Outlook uri scheme. Both are provided below

```
browserLaunch("ms-outlook://events/open?account={my.account@email.com}&restid={id}");


private async void browserLaunch( string uri ) {
    await Browser.OpenAsync(uri, BrowserLaunchMode.SystemPreferred);
}
```

The exact call I've been making to the Graphs API is as follows

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendarview?startdatetime=2020-01-23T15:54:40.377Z&enddatetime=2020-01-30T15:54:40.377Z
```

which returns a list of even items with the following scheme:

```
        "@odata.etag": "string",
            "id": "string",
            "createdDateTime": "20##-##-##T##:##:##.######Z",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "20##-##-##T#3:##:##.#######Z",
            "changeKey": "string",
            "categories": [],
            "originalStartTimeZone": "Central Standard Time",
            "originalEndTimeZone": "Central Standard Time",
            "iCalUId": "string",
            "reminderMinutesBeforeStart": int,
            "isReminderOn": true/false,
            "hasAttachments": true/false,
            "subject": "string",
            "bodyPreview": "string",
            "importance": "string",
            "sensitivity": "string",
            "isAllDay": true/false,
            "isCancelled": true/false,
            "isOrganizer": true/true,
            "responseRequested": true/false,
            "seriesMasterId": null,
            "showAs": "string",
            "type": "string",
            "webLink": "https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?itemid={id}&exvsurl={int}&path=/calendar/item",
            "onlineMeetingUrl": null,
            "recurrence": null,
            "responseStatus": {
                "response": "none",
                "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
            },
            "body": {
                "contentType": "html",
                "content": "string"
            },
            "start": {
                "dateTime": "20##-##-##T##:##:##.#######",
                "timeZone": "UTC"
            },
            "end": {
                "dateTime": "20##-##-##T##:##:##.#######",
                "timeZone": "UTC"
            },
            "location": {
                "displayName": "string",
                "locationType": "string",
                "uniqueId": "string",
                "uniqueIdType": "stirng"
            },
            "locations": [
                {
                    "displayName": "string",
                    "locationType": "string",
                    "uniqueId": "hexstrin-hexs-hexs-hexs-hexstringhex",
                    "uniqueIdType": "string"
                }
            ],
            "attendees": [
                {
                    "type": "string",
                    "status": {
                        "response": "string",
                        "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
                    },
                    "emailAddress": {
                        "name": "string",
                        "address": "my.account@email.com"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "organizer": {
                "emailAddress": {
                    "name": "string",
                    "address": "my.account@email.com"
                }
            }
```

I've also tried different ids that are given by the graphs API for the restid param. Thus far I've used the itemid param found in the url of the webLink field, the id of the json object, the changeKey, and the iCalUId but those last two didnt get me anything beyond just opening up Outlook.

I've also just passed in the webLink but it just opens a lightweight browser (and get's stuck on a white page) which I don't want as I need it specifically to go to the Outlook app. Any ideas?

Comment: Hey ! I didn't quite understand what problem you are having and what you are trying to do. Could you please explain the first paragraph? "I'm currently .... provided below"?

Comment: So the feature goes as such: the app calls the microsoft graph api to get a user's events, and then displays each event in a list view. Each list item then corresponds to an event on the user's outlook calendar. What I'm trying to do is give a button to each list view item that, when pressed, will take you to the details activity of the outlook calendar event that the list view item represents. I've gotten the button to open the outlook app to the calendar or open with an error, but I can't get the button to open the details of the outlook calendar event

Comment: Ok thank you. And do you want to open the details of the even in the outlook app, or your own app? And what documentation are you using to get that AppLink? Also have you tried these https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57618826/how-to-open-android-outlook-application-from-an-external-one/58002186#58002186

Comment: I want to open the details page within outlook, and yes, I've tried about a hundred or so different variations of "ms-outlook://events/open?restid=%s&account=test@om.com" within my app with no luck. However, using that scheme, I did get a message saying "Event couldn't be opened" so I tried a bunch of different ids for events. I haven't tried the immutable id because the graph api hasn't provided me with any on my api calls

Comment: "Event couldn't be opened" seems the most right. Did you make sure to make the ever public, maybe you didn't have the right accesss? Also what was the schema you had when you got that message?

Comment: the event is public (at least not set to private), and the schema I used was "ms-outlook://events/open?restid=%s&account=test@om.com" and "ms-outlook://events/open?account=test@om.com&restid=%s" which was passed as a string into my browserLaunch method defined in the first code block of the main question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the best current solution I have been able to find is to open up a lightweight browser using a different url scheme than any prior:

```
https://outlook.office365.com/calendar/item/{webLinkItemId}
```

where webLinkItemId is the itemId param from the webLink url gotten from the returned Graphs API json object. You can find that complete object above in my original post but what you're looking for within that object is the following field

```
"webLink": "https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?itemid={webLinkItemId}&exvsurl={int}&path=/calendar/item"
```

You want to take the {webLinkItemId} string embedded in the url above and plug it into the corresponding spot in the scheme above